# Removing Anomalies from tables

Tags: database, dependencies, relation

I have this table and I am supposed to re-design it to remove all anomalies from it. I will not give the table but the dependencies.

```
The functional dependencies are
(Product, Store) -> Dept
Store -> Manager
Dept-> Assist
(Product, Store)->Price
Product-> Weight
Product-> Manufact
Manufact-> Manuloc
```

Product and Store are the keys in this relation

Ok so I have to remove the anomalies by breaking up the table and creating new ones and state what will be in each table. I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: What database software are you using?

Comment: Im not using software, I just need to break up the table and make new ones to remove anomalies, I am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: Are you that currently you have a single table with all those attributes?

Comment: yes all of this is currently in one table and product and store are the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Armstrong's axioms and the rules derived from them. (I'm sure this is in your textbook. Check the index.) For example, given these two functional dependencies (FDs):

```
(Product, Store) -> Dept
Dept -> Assist
```

you can apply the transitivity rule to determine an unstated FD:

```
(Product, Store) -> Assist
```

From the FDs you're given, derive an *irreducible set* of FDs; this set determines your tables.

This example is from Date's *Introduction to Database Systems*. (He gives a more complete treatment of it.) Given

```
A  -> BC
B  -> C
A  -> B
AB -> C
AC -> D
```

rewrite for right-hand singletons using Armstrong's axioms:

```
A  -> B
A  -> C
B  -> C
A  -> B
AB -> C
AC -> D
```

The FD `A -> B` occurs twice; we can discard one without losing information. We can reduce `AC -> D` to `A -> D`, and we can eliminate `AB -> C`. And we can eliminate `A -> C`, leaving

```
A -> B
B -> C
A -> D
```

From this irreducible set of FDs, you'd derive the two tables

```
A -> BD
B -> C
```